# How to append text in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this form for inputting the birthday in html. But I only have a single column for storing it in wampserver(Column Birthday).

```
<select title="- Select Month -" name="mm" id="mm" class="" > 
                              <option value="" SELECTED >Month</option> 
                              <option value="1" >Jan</option> 
                              <option value="2"  >Feb</option> 
                              <option value="3"  >Mar</option> 
                              <option value="4"  >Apr</option> 
                              <option value="5"  >May</option> 
                              <option value="6"  >Jun</option> 
                              <option value="7"  >Jul</option> 
                              <option value="8"  >Aug</option> 
                              <option value="9"  >Sep</option> 
                              <option value="10"  >Oct</option> 
                              <option value="11"  >Nov</option> 
                              <option value="12"  >Dec</option> 
                              </select> 
                      <input title="Day" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="dd" value="" size="1" maxlength="2" id='numbers'/ > 
                      <input title="Year" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="yyyy"  value="" size="1"  maxlength="4" id='numbers'/> </td>
```

Do you have any idea on how I can place those 3 values in the same column?Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're posting that data you can do:

```
$date = $_POST['yyyy'] . '-' . $_POST['mm'] . '-' . $_POST['dd']; // 2010-04-18
```

Then

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(myDate) VALUES('$date')"; //assuming pre-validation of the data
```

Beign `myDate` a column with a DATE data type.

PS:

> The format of a DATE value is
>   'YYYY-MM-DD'. According to standard
>   SQL, no other format is allowed. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html

If you need another data format use PHP.

Comment: lol, user225269 - never think yourself, never think yourself, never think yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to compose the individual fields into a single date value.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in mysql should be stored in [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) datatype

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy

```
<input title="Day" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="dd" value="" size="1" maxlength="2" id='numbers'/ > 
<input title="month" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="mm" value="" size="1" maxlength="2" id='numbers'/ > 
<input title="Year" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="yyyy"  value="" size="1"  maxlength="4" id='numbers'/> </td>
```